# Stuff-Classifier Gem with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

im trying to deploy my ruby code to heroku 
this is my Gemfile ,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'googlecharts'
gem 'stuff-classifier'
gem 'devise'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :production do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and im getting this on push

```
HengHongs-MacBook-Pro:collab Kinnovate$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 19, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 1.44 KiB, done.
Total 16 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Using rake (0.9.2.2)
       Using i18n (0.6.0)
       Using multi_json (1.3.6)
       Using activesupport (3.2.6)
       Using builder (3.0.0)
       Using activemodel (3.2.6)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using journey (1.0.4)
       Using rack (1.4.1)
       Using rack-cache (1.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.1)
       Using hike (1.2.1)
       Using tilt (1.3.3)
       Using sprockets (2.1.3)
       Using actionpack (3.2.6)
       Using mime-types (1.19)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.10)
       Using mail (2.4.4)
       Using actionmailer (3.2.6)
       Using arel (3.0.2)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
       Using activerecord (3.2.6)
       Using activeresource (3.2.6)
       Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
       Using execjs (1.4.0)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
       Using json (1.7.5)
       Using rdoc (3.12)
       Using thor (0.16.0)
       Using railties (3.2.6)
       Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Using orm_adapter (0.4.0)
       Using warden (1.2.1)
       Using devise (2.1.2)
       Using fast-stemmer (1.0.1)
       Using googlecharts (1.6.8)
       Using jquery-rails (2.1.1)
       Installing msgpack (0.4.7) with native extensions
       Using pg (0.14.0)
       Using bundler (1.2.0)
       Using rails (3.2.6)
       Using sass (3.2.1)
       Using sass-rails (3.2.5)
       Installing sequel (3.20.0)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2wrfyq245cb6w/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2wrfyq245cb6w/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

it works fine when i remove stuff-classifier gem from the Gemfile

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

forked the repo and removed sqlite dependancy from gemspec file

added this to gemfile

```
gem 'stuff-classifier' , :git =>'https://github.com/henghonglee/stuff-classifier'
```